# Does a micro-HDMI (type D) cable with an adapter work normally for computer-monitor connection?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, external-display

I'm considering using a micro-HDMI (type D) to HDMI cable with an adapter on the micro-HDMI end to connect my computer to my monitor. I want to use micro-HDMI because I'm passing the cable through a conduit in the wall and I don't want the hole in the wall to be huge.

Specifically, I want to know if a micro-HDMI cable would be different (apart from the size) or have some limitation compared to regular HDMI. I want to output 1080p to two monitors. My graphics card has got two outputs.

So, can I use an adapter with a micro-HDMI to HDMI cable to connect my computer to my monitors?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has the following to say about [micro-HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Connectors) (emphasis mine):

> A Micro connector ... **keeps the standard 19 pins of types A and C** but shrinks the connector size to something resembling a micro-USB connector. ... The pin assignment is different from Type A or C.

Since the only thing that changes from HDMI to micro-HDMI is the pin assignments and not the number of pins, it's reasonable to conclude that connecting an HDMI device (with an appropriate adapter) through a micro-HDMI to HDMI cable would work.